# Cerberus not start when mobile restart

Tags: miui, xiaomi

Hello I have a Xiaomi redmi 3 Pro with MIUI 8 and I installed the app `cerberus` and I have made the app is not shown in the menu. The problem is this, I restarted the phone and want to access the app now, I put the code 23723787 for show the app in the menu and I also tried to send a command from the web and I have not received a response. It is as if the app had not started after restarting mobile.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some information I found the way.
You have to go to `Settings -> permissions -> autostart` and check the App Cerberus and other apps you want start automatically. Then I restart the phone and try the code or the web command and this work for me.

I found other way if you want to delete the App and then install it again. This way involves installing the App ROM Toolbox, that lets you delete a hidden App without being root and then install Cerberus again and follow the steps before.

This work for me, I hope this is the best way to do it, but I appreciate it corrected if I'm wrong.